# With repetition, no order. Probability of drawing atleast 18 distinct balls, when there are 20 different balls and one has 50 draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came up with this today, however I could not figure out a solution to this problem. 
Say, you have a pool of 20 different balls. Therefore, the probability of drawing one of the balls is equal to drawing any other. Also, you have 50 draws. 
Our variables so far are: 
n=20 (# of balls)
k=50 (# of moves)
p=5% (% of a certain ball).
Obviously, the number of combinations in this problem is: nCr(20+50-1;50).
Additionally, in the a-th draw the probability of drawing a yet undrawn ball is: (1-p)^a.
Could you please explain to me what the solution to this problem is and how it works? I am looking forward to reading your answers and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the numbers arbitrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to find the probability that there are *not* at least 18 distinct balls in the set of 50 draws, i.e. that there are three or more balls which do not appear.

There are $20^{50}$ possible sequences of 50 draws, all of which we assume are equally likely.  We would like to count the number of sequences in which three or more balls do not appear.  To that end, we use an extension of the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion (PIE).  Reference: *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications* by William Feller, Volume I, Third Edition, Section IV.5(a), "The Realization of at Least $m$ Events".

To apply PIE, let's say a sequence of 50 draws has "Property $i$" if ball $i$ does not appear in the sequence, for $1 \le i \le 20$.  We define $S_j$ to be the number of sequences with $j$ of the properties, for $1 \le j \le 20$.  If $j$ of the balls do not appear, then there are $\binom{20}{j}$ ways to pick the missing balls, and then there are $(20-j)^{50}$ possible sequences of the remaining balls.  So
$$S_j = \binom{20}{j} (20-j)^{50}$$
The extension of PIE we will use is that the number of sequences with at least $m$ of the properties is
$$N_m=S_m - \binom{m}{m-1} S_{m+1} + \binom{m+1}{m-1}S_{m+2} - \binom{m+2}{m-1}S_{m+3} + \dots \pm \binom{N-1}{m-1}S_N$$
In our case we have $m=3$ and $N=20$, so
$$N_3=S_3 - \binom{3}{2} S_{4} + \binom{4}{2}S_{5} - \binom{5}{2}S_{6} + \dots - \binom{19}{2}S_{20}=1.98074 \times 10^{64}$$
The probability that three or more balls do not appear in the sequence of 50 draws is
$$\frac{N_3}{20^{50}} = 0.175925$$
and the answer to the original problem, the probability that at least 18 balls appear, is
$$1-0.175925=\boxed{0.824075}$$

Comment: This question is a variation of the "Coupon Collector's Problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem